# Update View After Sort Method Runs on Button Click

Tags: reactjs

UPDATED:

In my react app, I'm trying to update the page so that a list of cars are displayed alphabetically, but I'm not sure how to replace the existing display with the updated array of cars.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CarCard from '../components/CarCard';
import CarForm from './CarForm';
import './Cars.css';
import { getCars } from '../actions/cars';

Component.defaultProps = {
cars: { cars: [] }
}

class Cars extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.sortAlphabetically = this.sortAlphabetically.bind(this)
}
state = {
    cars: []
};

this.setState({
    sortedCars: newArray
})

sortAlphabetically = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()   
    const newArray = [].concat(this.props.cars.cars)
        newArray.sort(function (a,b) {
            var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
            var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
            if (nameA < nameB) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (nameA > nameB) {
                return 1;
                } 
                return 0;
            })
        return newArray
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCars()
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="CarsContainer">
        <h3>Cars Container</h3> 
            <button onClick={this.sortAlphabetically}>Sort</button>
            {this.props.cars.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard delete={this.props.delete} key={car.id} car={car} />)}            
            <CarForm />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    cars: state.cars
  })
}


   export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCars })(Cars);
```

UPDATED: I added this.setState per the comments, but it gets a `parsing error`

I was told that I shouldn't use any other component lifecycle methods, but I'm not sure how to update the page with the result of the button click.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function and store the sorted cars on state. For that you use `this.setState({
   sortedCars: [results of your inlined function]
})`

Updating state always updates the component. Alternatively you could store and read them from redux if you need them in another component.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import CarCard from '../components/CarCard';
    import CarForm from './CarForm';
    import './Cars.css';
    import { getCars } from '../actions/cars';

    Component.defaultProps = {
      cars: { cars: [] }
    }

    class Cars extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
         cars: []
       };

       this.sortAlphabetically = this.sortAlphabetically.bind(this)
    }


sortAlphabetically = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()   
    const newArray = [].concat(this.props.cars.cars)
        newArray.sort(function (a,b) {
            var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
            var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
            if (nameA < nameB) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (nameA > nameB) {
                return 1;
                } 
                return 0;
            })
    this.setState({
        sortedCars: newArray
    })
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCars()
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="CarsContainer">
        <h3>Cars Container</h3> 
            <button onClick={this.sortAlphabetically}>Sort</button>
            {this.props.cars.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard delete={this.props.delete} key={car.id} car={car} />)}            
            <CarForm />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    cars: state.cars
  })
}
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCars })(Cars);

Comment: Thanks, I added that within my Cars class, but I'm getting a `parse error`. Does this have to do with how `this` is bound in my `constructor`?

Comment: I think it's where you have the `setState`. Moved that into the sort and the state definition into the constructor.

Comment: Strange, it's still not updating the UI. I think I need to get more specific with what I'm sorting (the name attribute of the car objects within the array of cars).

Conversely, I get an undefined error in the console when I type in `newArray`. Why do I not have access to that array?